# Lebesgue integrability of $\sin(\frac 1x)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let  $f= \sin(\frac 1x)$. I would now like to know whether $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $(0,1)$.

I know that $f$ must be measurable, since it it continuous. I am not quite sure how to check integrability...

I know $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if for $$\int_{(0,1)}f\ d\lambda = \int_{(0,1)}f^+\ d\lambda - \int_{(0,1)}f^-\ d\lambda$$
the two (or atleast one for semi integrability) summands are smaller than infinity,i.e: $$\int_{(0,1)}f^-\ d\lambda < \infty \ \ \  \hbox{and}\ \ \ \int_{(0,1)}f^+\ d\lambda < \infty$$

I figured that I can bound $|\sin(\frac 1x)|\le 1$, so I thought maybe, for a sequence $f_n \nearrow f$, I could just chose a sequence $g_n \nearrow g$, where $g$ denotes the constant function $x\mapsto 1$, with $g_n\ge f_n$. Then it would follow that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable. Is this argument valid, or do I need to show this in another way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A bounded function on a bounded interval is integrable if and only if it is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous, except at $0$, and bounded.
It is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ so certainly Lebesgue
integrable on $(0,1)$.

(A function $[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded
and its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.)

Comment: This does make sense in a way, but can I show it without using Riemann integrability? Say, I have never heard of the Riemann integral before, what would I do then?

Comment: @Jack4t3 It is bounded and Lebesgue measurable.